# Adding HTML attributes before/after text content

Tags: jquery

I am using this selector with the jQuery column selector

```
$(function() {
    $('#resultTable tbody td:nth-col(8)');
});
```

The text that is in the table column is the image source path on my server.  I would like to display this text as an img src picture rather than displaying the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//Make sure the selector for the alltd variable below is selecting all the td elements you need since you didn't post any HTML I can't tell if thats selecting everything correctly.

```
alltd = $('#resultTable tbody td:nth-col(8)').toArray();

$.each(alltd, function(i,e) {
    var imgText = $(e).html();
    $(e).html("<img src='" + imgText + "' />");
});
```

Comment: The text that is in the table column is the image source path on my server.  I would like to display this text as an img src picture rather than displaying the text.

Comment: Is there a reason you're rendering this from your server as text first, and not directly as the image? (eg. `<img src="<?php echo $text; ?>" />`)

Comment: function {
   var src = $('#resultTable tbody td:nth-col(8)').html();
   $('#resultTable tbody td:nth-col(8)').html('<img src="' + src + '" />');

Comment: Tried this function and it seems to apply the first result to every result in the column (ie the first row's picture shows up in every row.)